# Grouping 2 lines of code in a helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, helper

I have a method in my application_helper and 2 lines of code (the last ones in a method) that won't work if they both are active. How to group them in the proper way? (Choosing a code line depends on what page user opens).

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  css_class = sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
  direction = sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  link_to title, params.merge(sort: column, controller: 'analyze/consumptions', action: 'grid_report' , direction: direction), {class: css_class, remote: true, method: 'post'}
  link_to title, params.merge(sort: column, controller: 'admin/users', action: 'records' , direction: direction), {class: css_class}
end
```

Comment: How do you decide which one should be active?

Comment: It depends on what page user opens (sorting table columns is used in 2 different pages of my app)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. First you mentioned "grouping 2 lines of code" afterwards you say "choosing a code line". What exactly do you mean by "grouping lines of code" ?

Comment: That method is for sorting some table columns. I need the first line work when a user opens page 1 and second line work when a user opens page 2. Right now sorting works only for the page 2, because that code is on the last line. I need to make some if else statement maybe, but I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: `if page == 1` springs to mind...

Comment: Can I specify a page route or page view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the return value from your `sortable` helper method will be added to the buffer.

You can explicitly concatenate all values you wish to include (both link_to's), and return the entire string.

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  css_class = sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
  direction = sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"

  "".html_safe.tap do |buffer|  # Be sure you do not have unsafe content when using html_safe
    buffer << link_to(title, params.merge(sort: column, controller: 'analyze/consumptions', action: 'grid_report' , direction: direction), {class: css_class, remote: true, method: 'post'})
    buffer << link_to(title, params.merge(sort: column, controller: 'admin/users', action: 'records' , direction: direction), {class: css_class})
  end  # The entire buffer will be returned.
end
```

Note: It seems to me like it would be better to separate `sortable` into two different methods, one for each link you wish to render.

Comment: Thanks, I split it into two different methods